# Adding ImageView in XML File causes program to stop unexpectedly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am attempting to add a tiled image as a background of the program.

The code that I am currently using in main.xml, which is crashing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:src="@drawable/cartoonclouds"
android:contentDescription="@string/desc" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
</ImageView>
```

However, when the `ImageView` is removed and the `xmlns` is moved to the `LinearLayout`, it functions fine (without, of course, the image).

I can't see any related errors in LogCat.

More information:

Using Eclipse and Android 2.2, API 8. The program runs but crashes instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not put anything in an ImageView.  It's not a layout.  Use the `background` attribute of the `LinearLayout` to set the background to your image.

Another option would be to wrap everything in a `RelativeLayout`.  Separate the `ImageView` and the `LinearLayout`.  The image will fill the `RelativeLayout` and the `LinearLayout` will be on top of it.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/cartoonclouds"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/hello" />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did the job perfectly. However, how do I get the image to tile?

Comment: That I don't know.  I've never tried.  With `ImageView` it merely scales images.  The `background` attribute does the same thing.  This might warrant another question because I'm curious if it's possible too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899222/tiling-images-in-android-with-imageview-in-xml

Answer (score 0):

You should not add a linear layout inside an imageview. Have a linearlayout at the top as root and then add the image view in there